# iPhone - difference between topViewController and other forms

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am on a delegate of a NavigationControl based app.

when I try to access the rootViewController using

```
RootViewController *rootViewController = (RootViewController *)[navigationController topViewController];
```

to run a method, it crashes, saying the method is "unknown" on the rootViewController.

When I access the rootViewController using this

```
RootViewController *rootViewController = (RootViewController *)[navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

it works.

Which object is the first line accessing?

thanks

Comment: `it crashes, saying the method is "unknown" on the rootViewController.` Could you paste the exact error?

Comment: "unknown selector sent to object..." watching both on debugger I see they return different objects...

Comment: You mean `navigationController` in one of your examples and `navigationController` in the other example aren't the same thing? I was under the assumption based on your wording of the question that you were trying to use them on the exact same line, interchangeably.

Comment: No, I have tried the first one it didn't work. Then I changed to the second one, it worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`topViewController` of a navigation controller represents the view controller at the top of the stack. Index `0` is the bottom. `topViewController` is the object at index `0` only when one view controller is on the stack. If you have more than one, it is not the same. I am guessing that it is the case as it's crashing because the `topViewController` doesn't know how to respond to messages intended for a `RootViewController` instance.

Comment: The app has several viewControllers but they are just created lazily. In theory, after the delegate initializes it will initialize the RootViewController, and there's no other viewController initialized at this time. This is why I don't understand this.

Answer (score 4):

You can check what type of class is being returned with

```
    NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([[self.navigationController topViewController] class]); 
    NSLog(@"class name is: %@", className);
```

If you want to check before accessing, I'd use:

```
if ([[self.navigationController topViewController] isKindOfClass:[RootViewController class]])
```

Comment: the first one returns Main and the second one returns RootViewController that is what I want. The big question is: what is this "Main" view controller? I have not created that, at least not that I know. I have started the project using the NavigationController template from Xcode.

Comment: you solved my one of the biggest problem ... thannnkkkssssssss