# iOS: trouble sharing data between two view controllers

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

I have an app, which has a first view controller called MainViewController that's sorta like a stopwatch, and when I click finish, it displays a UIAlertView pushes another view controller, EndViewController, which shows how long the stopwatch was running and how long it was paused. I am getting the following errors:

```
My Point[851:c07] -[EndViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x754db60

My Point[851:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[EndViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x754db60'
```

Can anyone point ou to me what's wrong?

heres my code:

MainViewController.h:

```
#import "EndViewController.h"
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *out;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *in;
@end
```

MainViewController.m:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"endtask"]){
        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        EndViewController *controller = (EndViewController *)navController.topViewController;
        controller.timeIn.text=_in.text;

    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Are you sure?"
                                                    message:nil
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"NO"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        //do nothing
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1) {

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"endtask" sender:self];
    }}

- (IBAction)endButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    [_alert show];
}
- (IBAction)endButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    [_alert show];
}
```

EndViewController.h:

```
@interface EndViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timeIn;
@end
```

Comment: Try logging segue.destinationViewController in prepareForSegue, and see what that gives you.

Comment: This may help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563597/iphone-difference-between-topviewcontroller-and-other-forms

Answer (score 0):

You're calling a method named `topViewController` on an object which doesn't have the method/property. It's this line here:

```
EndViewController *controller = (EndViewController *)navController.topViewController;
```

I would suspect its because the view controller you are assigning to `navController` isn't *actually* a navigation controller, but is something else. Check your storyboards/nibs for this.

Also, try logging `navController`, as one commentor said, and see what that gives you.

```
NSLog(@"%@", navController);
```

Comment: I don't know very much about this, but I have a view controller which is the root view controller connected to the navigation controller, and then that controller pushes the MainViewController to the top of the stack

Comment: @dietbacon What does the log give you?

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing a string with timeIn you should have @property of a NSString in the endViewController.h

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * timeIn ;
```

Then in you endViewController.m you put the timeIn into a labe for example.

```
myLabel.text = timeIn;
```

Comment: I have changed that, but it's not the problem :(

Comment: Do you get what u want from _in.text? Have u tried to log it? You might want use the string from the label and not the label itself. If I understand it correctly.